# Docusign - no_valid_keys_or_signatures

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated docusign API and it worked perfectly. Suddenly we are getting this error when sending envelops. We found there is an issue with generating JWT token API.

Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"no_valid_keys_or_signatures"}

Answer (score 4):

Generally this happens when an invalid RSA private key is used to sign the JWT assertion. I would suggest generating a new private key and seeing if that works.